# Probability that fewer than 38 people paid for in flight movies. (CLT)

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

American Airlines claims that the average number of people who pay for in-flight movies when the plane is fully loaded is $42$ with a standard deviation of $8$. A sample of $36$ fully loaded planes is taken. What is the probability that fewer than 38 people paid for in-flight movies?

Ans is $0.0013$. We get this answer if we find $p(\mu<38)$, but I don't understand why we have taken the distribution of mean and not summation as the question has asked for the number of people who have paid not **average** no of people who paid.
But if I find the total number of people who paid for in-flight movies less than $38$ by CLT, I get $P(z<-50.)$ something which is $0$.

Comment: Kindly use MathJax to improve readibility.

Comment: As it's currently worded you are correct in studying the distribution of the sample sum and not the sample mean.

Comment: What does the sample size of 36 have to do with the question?

Comment: @GregMartin I assume the problems wants the student to approximate $$\mathbb{P}\left(X_1+\dots +X_{36}<38\right)$$ where $X_j$ is the number of people who pay for in flight movies in the $j^{\text{th}}$ plane sampled.

Comment: ya I too feel so but like this I am not getting the answer. P(Z<(38-1512)/48)..